# How to return the correct datatype with MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

below is the code i am using -

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("sample");
MongoCollection<Document> imagescollaction = database.getCollection("images");
System.out.println("_id value  : " + imagescollaction.find().first().get("_id"));
```

**output of program : _id value  : 0.0**

**out put from image collection from mongo shell**

**db.images.find();**

```
{ "_id" : 0, "height" : 480, "width" : 640, "tags" : [ "dogs", "work"
] }     
{ "_id" : 1, "height" : 480, "width" : 640, "tags" : [ "cats",
"sunrises", "kittens", "travel", "vacation", "work" ] }
```

**My question : from the mongo shell i can see those values are Long or Integer but when i am querying from the java mongo driver using find method it is printing Double. Does anybody know why is this happening.**

***Mongo driver i am using :  3.0.0***

Comment: The MongoDB 3.0 version of the Java driver does allow casting of the types and specific method to retrieve by the cast type. However if these are a "mix" of types then that is probably not a good idea. Especially when working with a strongly typed language it is wise to use the same type for a given field. Especially the primary key. Are you certain they are different types? Can you produce mongo shell output that shows different types? There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32625607/edit) link on your question for additional information.

Comment: @BlakesSeven :  non of the document has Double values for ID. i have checked it only has Long value.

Comment: Please show a document or two from shell output. BSON does not have a "Long" type. There are only 32-bit and 64-bit Integers, and of course Double. Your current output suggests Double, but it's not clear if that is console output or from the shell itself.

Comment: @BlakesSeven : I have pasted the output from the shell i my question. since i am unable to insert images . i have copy pasted the documents from the mongo shell.

Comment: Then those values are Double values. As I said there is no Long.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  why by default _Id is taken as double. java equivalent datatype should be Integer right ? as you are saying Long cannot be typecasted to.

Comment: I already changed your question title as the "default" type is an `ObjectId`. The values you have present have been explicitly set by other code. If you expect something different then it is the other code writing this that is at fault.

Comment: @BlakesSeven : thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inserting using mongoshell, you need to explicitly say NumberInt(0) or NumberLong(0) if you want to have integer values. Otherwise, MongoDB will use floating point values.

When you do a find() in mongodb shell, it will also return NumberInt(0) or NumberLong(0) if it is an integer.

Comment: you are exactly correct i tried this now. actually mongo shell should show this thing if it is double 0.0 like this. which was confusing.